# Need to get certain words from a long string swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

So I have a this long text string and I need to get the words that are in the { } so I can put these in an array.

This is the string: `<p style=\"text-align:center\">There will be some text here.<br><br>Send More Text in here<br><br>${LogoSquare}  ${WUSquare}  ${VisaSquare}</p>"`

I have a regEx to see when I've reach the words that I need:

```
static let regEX = "^.*\\b(LogoSquare|WUSquare|VisaSquare)\\b.*$"
```

With the following function

```
fun containsValues(text: String) -> Bool {
    if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: AdviceCardRegexPattern.mytd, options: [.dotMatchesLineSeparators]) {
        return (regex.firstMatch(in: text, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count)) != nil)
    }
    return false
}
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
var components = textPayload.components(separatedBy: ">")
```

I do the above so that the values get separated from the last > so it becomes like this

`"${LogoSquare}  ${WUSquare}  ${VisaSquare}</p", ""]`

Then I have:

```
let removal: [Character] = ["$", "{", "}", "<", "/"]
var imageTags: [String] = []
for value in components {
    if containsValues(text: value) {
        imageTags.append(value.filter { !removal.contains($0)})
    }
}
```

This prints the following:

["LogoSquare WUSquare VisaSquarep"]

The only thing that's left is getting rid of the p at the end of VisaSquare

Comment: What does "remove them from the string" mean? Given the original input string you cited, what should the output string be?

Comment: Also I don't get what the `regEx` is for, with `LogoSquare|WUSquare|VisaSquare`. This presupposes that you know what the words _are_. Isn't the point that you don't know what they are, but you know they are in the `${...}` delimiters?

Comment: yes sorry, the words might change so it has to be the words inside the ${...}, you made me realize that my regEx is incorrect.

Comment: So what's your desired end goal? Something like `There will be some text here. Send More Text in here` or an array `["LogoSquare", "WUSquare","VisaSquare"]`?

Comment: an array of ["LogoSquare", "WUSquare","VisaSquare"]

Comment: So what is the “remove” part???

Comment: sorry, I removed that part. For now I would just like some help on having an array that has the values inside the {...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're over-thinking this. Just match against `${something}` and capture the `something`. For instance:

```
let s = "hey nonny nonny ${LogoSquare}  ${WUSquare}  ${VisaSquare} yoho yo"
let r = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\$\\{(.*?)\\}")
var result = [String]()
let ss = s as NSString
for m in r.matches(in: s, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, ss.length)) {
    result.append(ss.substring(with: m.range(at: 1)))
}
print(result)
```

Comment: LIFESAVER Thank you so much! Marked as approved answer